# Problems deploying my meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment

I'm following the Meteor tutorial. I'm on step 6 - Deploying your app and I keep getting the following message. I've tried all of the suggested resolutions with no success.
Terminal Message:

```
> Macintosh-2:simple-todos kmcrayton7$ meteor deploy
> my_app_name.meteor.com Sorry, that site belongs to a different user. 
> You are currently logged in as kmcrayton7.
> 
> Either have the site owner use 'meteor authorized --add' to add you as
> an authorized developer for the site, or switch to an authorized
> account with 'meteor login'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that somebody else already has a Meteor app named "my_app_name" (or, if that's a placeholder, whatever the name really is) deployed.

So you are, in effect, trying to update it when you "meteor deploy my_app_name"

Use a different name, such as `meteor deploy my_app_name42` and it should work, and be available at `my_app_name42.meteor.com`

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a different name for your app - many people have created that example before. Ex:

```
$ meteor deploy kc-todos.meteor.com
```